# How do I traverse a link list looking two nodes ahead?

Tags: java, c, linked-list

I have a link list, and I want to be able to look two nodes ahead. I need to check if the first two nodes have integers, and if they do, and the third node says ADD, then I need to condense that information into one node and free the other two nodes.

I'm confused about what should go in my while loop. I check if the third node points to null, but somehow that's not giving me the right output. I don't know if I'm handling my node.next correctly either. Some of this is pseudocode now.

```
while(node1.next.next.next != NULL){
    if((node1.data.isInteger() && (node2.data.isInteger()){
        if(node3.data.equals('add')){
            node1.data = node1.data + node2.data;
        } else {
            //ERROR
        }
        garbage_ptr1 = node2;
        garbage_ptr2 = node3;
        node1.next = node3.next;
        free(garbage_ptr1);
        free(garbage_ptr2);
        node2.next = node1.next.next;
        node3.next = node2.next.next;
   } else {
        node1.next = node1.next.next;
        node2.next = node1.next.next;
        node3.next = node2.next.next;
   }
```

Comment: try to iterate (traverse) you list in reverse order: when you see the operator ADD you know you have to sum two operands, the two next.

Comment: Inside your while loop can't you loop through nodes to look ahead 2?

Comment: Is it `queue` or `deque`?

Comment: Also, what happens with the outer loop if `node1` is null? Or `node1.next`, etc.?

Comment: @SMT Yes, I can, which is what I did, but I'm having trouble with the condition of the while loop. When should I end it so that it traverses every node until the end?

Comment: @Joachim I know, that's why I said it's pseudocode. I want this to apply to both C and Java later on

Comment: It looks like you need a Binary expression tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree

Comment: @Jay Have a check for NULL inside the while loop for the other nodes perhaps

Comment: @SMT So if I do that, then would my while condition just be while(node1!=NULL)?

Comment: @Jay loop to check if node1 is null then inside if node2 and node3 are integers add them, etc.

Comment: @SMT I did that but I'm getting a segmentation fault when running it

Comment: @jay test the other nodes for NLUL values before trying .isInteger() on them.

Comment: @SMT yep, I did that, but the problem is, node1 will never be null, so in my while condition, should I be testing if node1.next is null?

Comment: In the pseudocode node2 and node3 and being freed, then the next two statements node2.next and node3.next are being assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach that I find easier is to maintain a small array that acts as a window onto the list, and to look for matches on the array.  The code also becomes a lot cleaner and simpler if you move your null checks into utility methods.  By doing these things, the loop over the list only needs to check the last element of the window to terminate.

A sketch of this in Java:

```
/* small utility methods to avoid null checks everywhere */
public static Node getNext(Node n) { return n != null ? n.next : null; }

public static boolean isInteger(Node n) {
  return (n != null) && (n.data != null) && (n.data instanceof Integer);
}
public static boolean isAdd(Node n) { 
  return (n != null) && (n.data != null) && n.data.equals("add");
}

/* checks for a match in the 3-node window */
public boolean isMatch(Node[] w) {
  return isInteger(w[0]) && isInteger(w[1]) && isAdd(w[2]);
}

/* Loads the 3-node window with 'n' and the next two nodes on the list */
public void loadWindow(Node[] w, Node n) { 
  w[0] = n; w[1] = getNext(w[0]); w[2] = getNext(w[1]);
}

/* shifts the window down by one node */
public void shiftWindow(Node[] w) { loadWindow(w, w[1]); }

...
Node[] window = new Node[3];
loadWindow( window, node1 );
while (window[2] != null) {
  if (isMatch(window)) { 
    window[0].data = stack[0].data + stack[1].data;
    window[0].next = window[2].next;
    loadWindow(window, window[0]);  // reload the stack after eliminating two nodes
  } else {
    shiftWindow( window );
  }
}
```